# Can you access a clients com port from asp.net web app

Tags: asp.net

Is there by any chance a way in which you can access the Com port of a client which is accessing a web app hosted with asp.net mvc 4?

I think I could do this by writing a client c# app which communicates with the com port and then from the server make calls to the client app.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is maybe but not directly. Web applications cannot access client hardware outside of the limited sandbox in which a web browser runs. The application would need to be natively installed on the computer or device and be running under an account with the necessary permissions.

You could have a native application or service that communicates with the COM port and that then makes a web service call back to the server updating a data repository (database / file). Your MVC application could then refresh at intervals with this data (or if your feeling adventurous with something like [SignarR](http://www.asp.net/signalr)). However, the obvious problem is getting the user to install your native application, this may or may not be a problem for you.

Bear in mind also, that the complexity will also be in maintaining a list of users and their associated COM ports. As the data from the COM port will be outside of the user's browser session, you'll need to associate the 'ID' of the COM port with a user so that you can show them the correct data.